# Check the ending of a string

Tags: javascript, loops

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  var end = target;
  var match = '';

  for(var x = 0; x < str.length; x++){
      for(var j = 0; j < str[x].length; j++){
          if(str[x][j]){
             match = str[x][j];
          }
      }
  }
  return match.substr(-target.length) === target;
}

confirmEnding("He has to give me a new name", "name");
```

but I want to know if I can instead loop through the string and then check it using the appropriate indexes.

Can someone understand my approach and let me know how/why it's not doable?

It's currently only checking for the last character, so whole words aren't working.  I know the line below will work

```
return str.substr(-target.length) === target;
```

will work, but can someone help me with my approach

Edit:

I changed it more slightly, and got closer but still no luck.

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {

  for(var x = str.length-1; x < str.length; x++){
      for(var j = target.length-1; j>=0; j--){
          if(str[x] === target[j]){
              return true;
          } else{
             return false; 
          }
      }
  }

}

confirmEnding("Walking on water and developing software from a specification are easy if both are frozen", "specification");
```

That returns true, when it should return false.  I see why, but thinking of a resolve.

Comment: why all the complication of using the loop?

Comment: Also loop could go from right to left not left to right

Comment: @charlietfl When I play around with things, it helps me understand them better. I'm trying to understand how to use loops better. Also, not sure what you mean by right to left

Comment: Can loop through a string right to left by decrementing instead of incrementing `for(var i = str.length-1; i>=0; i--)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the loop is a strict requirement, then I would do it in a way

```
function confirmEnding(source, target) {
  var lengthT = target.length;
  var lengthS = source.length;
  for(var x = 0; x < lengthT; x++) {
    if(source[lengthS - 1 - x] !== target[lengthT - 1 - x]) {
       return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

confirmEnding("He has to give me a new name", "name"); // true
```

But the easier implementation of `confirmEnding` method would be just

```
function confirmEnding(source, target) {
  return source.substr(source.length - target.length, target.length) === target;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help :)

Comment: @JordanBrown :thumpub Your second approach is bad due to immediate return from the inner loop (it's not the only issue; anyway I can't imagine how two loops could be helpful here).

Comment: Yeah I actually realized that once I saw your code.
Can't use return before a loop finishes checking it's operations.

!== would be best followed by false and then return on the outside of the loop.